# iTextSharp : How to add 2 sentence in 1 line and adjust width of cells from datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, itext

I have a winform that enables user to key in via DataGridView and then converts the data into a PDF document.

However I am having trouble with the format of the Table where the Cells are not formatted correctly based on Width Size.

I have tried setting my DataGridView cells width into type "Fill" but it does not change the outcome when converted into a PDF.

Besides that , can we actually use iTextSharp to insert 2 different sentences in 1 Line.

```
Paragraph b1 = new Paragraph("OWNER NAME: " + "                                      " + "Property Name: ");

Paragraph b2 = new Paragraph("Property Name: " + "\n");
```

is there a way to combine b1 and b2?

Outcome should be as per picture.

Property name should be on the far right on the same line as "Owner Name".
And cells width should be based on Column Size configured in DataGridView

[image: ITARF]

EDIT 1 :

Adding my DataGridView conversion to PDF code below -

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.ColumnCount);
        //pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 10;
        pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
        pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

        //Adding Header row from DGV to PDFTable
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
            //cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240);
            pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
        }

        //Adding DataRow from DGV to PDFTable
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                try
                {
                    pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        //PDFVariablesForPathAndNaming
        int filecount = 0;
        int i;
        string path = pathtofile1;

        for (i = 0; File.Exists(path + @"YTLHPITARF_" + i + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".pdf"); i++)
        {
            filecount = i + 1;
        }

        string fileLoc = path + @"YTLHPITARF_" + filecount + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".pdf";
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(fileLoc);
        string pathtofile2 = pathtofile1 + filename;

        //ToBeUsedInDataBase
        dName = filename;

        //Start of PDF Creation
        Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fileLoc, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        //FontSizeAndFormat
        iTextSharp.text.Font head1 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 14, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);
        iTextSharp.text.Font head2 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
        iTextSharp.text.Font head3 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
        iTextSharp.text.Font bold1 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);

        Paragraph a1 = new Paragraph("ASSET RETURN FORM", head1);
        Paragraph a2 = new Paragraph("(due to Staff resign / Outlet close / Repair)" + "\n\n", head2);

        Paragraph b1 = new Paragraph("OWNER NAME: ", head3);
        b1 = new Paragraph();
        b1.Add(new Chunk("OWNER NAME: ", head3));
        iTextSharp.text.TabSettings tab = new TabSettings();
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
        b1.Add(new Chunk("Property Name: ", head3));

        Paragraph c1 = new Paragraph("SUBMITTED BY: "+ "\n\n" + "\n", head3);
        Paragraph d1 = new Paragraph("NAME: ", head3);
        Paragraph e1 = new Paragraph("DATE: " + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), head3);

        //Paragraph Alignment
        a1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        a2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

        //Paragraph Insertion
        document.Add(a1);
        document.Add(a2);
        document.Add(b1);
        pdfTable.SpacingBefore = 3f;
        document.Add(pdfTable);
        document.Add(c1);
        document.Add(d1);
        document.Add(e1);
        //document.Add(f1);
        //document.Add(g1);

        //CloseCreationOfPDF
        document.Close();

        //OpenCreatedPDF
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathtofile2);
}
```

Comment: For multiple parts in one line have a look at the [tabbing examples](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-5-legacy/tabbing-examples) (for Java, but the idea should be clear). For your table issue: iText does not directly access the `DataGridView`, most likely you retrieve a html form of it and feed that into the `XmlWorker`. Thus, please show that html and how you apply the `XmlWorker` to it.

Comment: @mkl - hi , i am not using html actually. im writing directly using C# winform and converting through itextsharp.

Comment: As far as I know itextsharp does not know winforms. Thus, please show how you are converting the winform through itextsharp.

Comment: @mkl - Let me add the code into the question above.

Comment: Please do so, there is an [edit] link right under your question.

Comment: hi @mkl , i have added my code. Thanks for the tabbing examples , i manage to do tabbing on my inline paragraph. Now i only need to figure out how to size the cells accordingly.

Comment: Hi , i have solved my problem. Thanks. :)

Comment: Ah, you actually read the data grid contents cell by cell. I misunderstood that (thus, please always show the pivotal code in your questions) . And ok, then you found the way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution]

In C# , to create an inline text with a tabbing is done as per below :

```
Paragraph c1 = new Paragraph("SUBMITTED BY: "+ "\n\n" + "\n", head3);
            c1 = new Paragraph();
            c1.Add(new Chunk("SUBMITTED BY : ", head3));
            c1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
            c1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
            c1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
            c1.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
            c1.Add(new Chunk("ACKNOWLEDGED/TAKEN BY : ", head3));
```

The Chunk.TABBING will create a space in between the text. As per picture below :
[image]

While to adjust cell width size , depending on how you convert your DataGridView into a PDF or such , here's the code :

```
PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.ColumnCount);
float[] widths1 = new float[] { 5f, 30f, 30f, 5f, 15f, 30f, 30f };
pdfTable.SetWidths(widths1);

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Font header1 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText, header1)) { BorderWidth = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
                //cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240);
                pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
            }
```

I created my pdftable with the columcount i have in DataGridView.
With this , i manually adjust the size of each columns width using float array. Picture above is already using this method.